# Determine whether the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^3}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question asks to use the direct comparison test to determine whether

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^3}$$

is convergent or divergent.

I was wondering whether the direct comparison test requires that a series consist of a positive sequence, as the only thing I could think of to compare the series to was:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{n^2}{n^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^3}$$

with the LHS being a negative harmonic series that diverges and hence shows the series on the right diverges as well.

Is this reasoning correct/is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: No, the reasoning is not at all correct: The series whose terms are all zero satisfies the same inequality.

Comment: Okay, so what do you suggest I do instead? @T.Bongers

Comment: Why don't you just start by computing, say, the first $10$ terms of the sequence?

Comment: I could do that, but the question asks specifically to use the direct comparison test. I am looking for a series to compare it to, I already know it diverges.

Comment: Well, if you compute each term and notice they're all larger than $1$ you should be able to complete the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to formulate this into a smaller series that diverges as well - again, I understand what you are saying it's just this question is asking very specifically to use the direct comparison test.

Comment: Yes, my comment said to apply direct comparison to the series whose terms are all $1$.......

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thank you very much @T.Bongers

Comment: This is unfortunately a bad question. It would be easier to use the divergence test (sometimes called nth term test) to show the series diverges, as in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $n! > n^3$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 1 = \infty$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the ratio test. We may drop the absolute values because the terms are always greater than zero.

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^3}\cdot\frac{n^3}{n!}\right|=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3(n+1)}{(n+1)^3}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{(n+1)^2}$$

Which obviously goes to infinity. Thus, the series diverges. Thanks to T. Bongers for helping.

Comment: Why on earth would you use L'Hospital's rule to compute that limit?

Comment: Yes, it works; but it's unnecessarily difficult and obfuscates what's actually going on....

Comment: Notice that it's equal to $$(n + 1) \cdot \frac{1}{(1 + 1/n)^3}$$ as an application of the standard technique of dividing by the highest-order term.

Comment: @zz20s $n^3/(n+1)^3\to 1$ clearly, so the limit you gave clearly goes to infinity.